# why do we return a value for uploading an image in this controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This is the part of a  controller which uploads files in ASP.net Core.
My question is why do we return a value for this case?

```
string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", imageData.File.FileName);
                using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(path))
                {
                    await imageData.File.CopyToAsync(stream);
                }

                Image file = await _context.Images.FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.FileName == imageData.File.FileName);
                if (file == null)
                {
                    Image image = new Image()
                    {
                        ContentType = imageData.File.ContentType,
                        DateModified = DateTime.Now,
                        FileName = imageData.File.FileName,
                        Path = path,
                        Description = imageData.Description
                    };
                    _context.Images.Add(image);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetImage), new { id = image.ImageId }, image);
                }
```

Comment: Suppose you want to display the image after uploading it? How would you refer to it?

Comment: I believe it's a standard pattern for REST API, after creating something, at least you should return its `Id` or even a URL pointing at the newly created resource. It's a standard pattern but you don't always have to follow it. It depends on your APIs design, on its usage scope as well as in agreement with other members working on that same APIs project.

Comment: You're asking US why code exists?  I think you should refer to the author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's common for any type of record, simultaneously confirming the creation and allowing you to make changes if required.